# android: draw continuous string on multiple textview

Tags: java, android

I need to create a multiple textview that holds a continuous string(like columns in newspaper and magazine)

is there anyway to make this possible?
any answers will be very helpful

thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved using a single `TextView`/`EditText`.

1. You can specify some element attributes in xml.
2. You can call certain methods on your `TextView`/`EditText`.

   < EditText android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:lines="5"/>

-- or --

```
textView.setLines(5);
textView.setTransformationMethod(new SingleLineTransformationMethod());
```

Comment: nicholas, it seems that using android:lines doesn't change a thing.
but i've been able to divide my string using subString() method
thank you for you response anyways :)